# Значение input`а в state компонента

Tags: reactjs

Есть input и кнопка. При нажатии на кнопку, текст введённый в инпут должен быть передан в state компонента Cards.

Comment: Ну раз должен, передавайте. В чем вопрос то?

Comment: вопрос в том как это сделать в реакте

Comment: Взять и сохранить. Покажите кодом, что делали и что не получилось. Из вопроса не понятно где находится инпут, кнопка и компонент cards